# Stored procedure keeps running - code works fine executed outside of the stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a SQL query that runs fine outside of the stored procedure. When I run it through the stored procedure, it just runs and never completes and seems to cause locks. Am I doing something simply wrong like missing a NO LOCK in the sql cmd query or if there something obvious I cant see that explains why this stored procedure runs for so long and causes blocking?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [USP_GET_INACTIVE_REPORTS_EMAIL]
-- Author: XXXXXXXXX
-- Version 1.4 - Ready for Production ( LOL ! ) 
AS
BEGIN
    set nocount on;
    declare @trancount int;
    set @trancount = @@trancount;

    begin try

        SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

        if @trancount = 0
            begin transaction usp_get_inactive_reports_email;
        else
            save transaction usp_get_inactive_reports_email;

        -- Step 1 - Create Temp Tables to hold Reporting DataSet for Active Reports that have not been executed in the last 30 days
        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##temp01') IS NOT NULL 
        BEGIN 
            DROP TABLE ##temp01
        END

        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##temp02') IS NOT NULL 
        BEGIN 
            DROP TABLE ##temp02
        END

        -- Step 2 - Query the Report Server Catalog and Execution Log for answers . Active reports defined as not being hidden and having a description populated.

        ;WITH RankedReports AS
        (
            SELECT 
                ReportID,
                TimeStart,
                UserName, 
                RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ReportID ORDER BY TimeStart DESC) AS iRank
            FROM 
                ReportServer.dbo.ExecutionLog t1
            JOIN 
                ReportServer.dbo.Catalog t2 ON t1.ReportID = t2.ItemID 
                                            AND t2.Type <> 1
        )
        SELECT DISTINCT     
            t1.UserName, t2.Name AS ReportName,
            TimeStart,
            SUBSTRING(t2.Path, 2, LEN(t2.Path) - LEN(t2.Name) - 1) AS Folder,
            t2.Type
        INTO ##temp01
        FROM RankedReports t1
        INNER JOIN ReportServer.dbo.Catalog t2 ON t1.ReportID = t2.ItemID
        WHERE t1.iRank = 1 
          AND t2.Type <> 1
          AND CAST(TimeStart AS DATE) > GETDATE() - 30
        ORDER BY t1.UserName, t2.Name;

        --- Select * from ##temp01 order by timestart


        SELECT 
            cast ( SUBSTRING(Path,2,LEN(Path)-LEN(Name)-1) as varchar(100)) AS ReportFolder
            ,Name AS ReportName
            ,CreationDate
            ,ModifiedDate
            ,Type,replace([Description],'~','/') as Description,Hidden
            INTO ##temp02
            FROM ReportServer.dbo.Catalog 
        WHERE Name NOT IN (SELECT ReportName FROM ##temp01) 
            AND Path <> '' 
            AND SUBSTRING(Path,2,LEN(Path)-LEN(Name)-1)<>''
            AND Description is not NULL 
            AND Type = 2 -- Means Report Type according to Mictosoft Docs for Report Server Schema
            AND cast (ModifiedDate as date )<Getdate() - 30
        OR (
              Hidden='0' --- Reports that we have shown as hidden ad soft deletes done in SSRS
              AND Name NOT IN (SELECT ReportName FROM ##temp01) 
                AND Path <> '' 
                AND SUBSTRING(Path,2,LEN(Path)-LEN(Name)-1)<>''
                AND Type = 2 -- Means Report Type according to Mictosoft Docs for Report Server Schema)
                AND cast (ModifiedDate as date )<Getdate() - 30
            )
            ORDER BY Path



    -- Step 3 - If the Query return no results then dont email. If it does email it to requestforchange@creditfix.co.uk


    declare @counter int
    ;with query as (

        SELECT ReportFolder
            ,ReportName
             ,CreationDate
            ,ModifiedDate
            ,Type,[Description],Hidden 
        FROM ##temp02 where Hidden=0 AND Description is not null 


            )
    select @counter = count(*) from query


    --- Step 4 - If the count of rows from Inactive Reports query >0 then Send the email about which reports to xxxxx

IF @counter > 0
BEGIN


--execute xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT '' ReportFolder,ReportName,CreationDate,ModifiedDate,Type,Description FROM ##temp02 WHERE ReportFolder <>''''AND Description is not NULL AND Type = 2 AND Hidden=0 ORDER BY 4" queryout C:\xxxxx\BI_Active_Reports_not_used_in_Last_30_days.csv -c -t, -S xxxxxx -U xxxxx -P xxxxxxx'

declare @fileNameTXT varchar(200) = '\\xxxxxx\Active_Reports_not_used_in_Last_30_days.csv'

declare @sql_bcp varchar(1000) = 'sqlcmd -S xxxxx -d xxxxxx Rep -E -Q "set nocount on; PRINT ''Reportname'' + '','' + ''ReportFolder'' ;SELECT  ReportName,ReportFolder FROM ##temp02 where Hidden=0 AND Description is not null  " -o ' + @filenameTXT + ' -W -h -1 -s"," -w 1500'

--print @sql_bcp


execute xp_cmdshell @sql_bcp

--- Send Email Section to export query contents to a CSV Output File 

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
    @profile_name = 'SMTP Server Mail',
    @recipients= 'xxxxxx',
    @subject = 'IT - Active Reports not used in the Last 30 days',
    @execute_query_database = 'ReportServer',
    @body = 'Greetings, <br><br>
    Please find attached Reports that have not been run in the last 30 days. 
    <br><br>
    Kind Regards 
    <br><br>
    xxxxxx Team',
    @body_format = 'HTML',
    @file_attachments= '\\xxxxx\Active_Reports_not_used_in_Last_30_days.csv'

    commit transaction usp_get_inactive_reports_email

END
ELSE
    BEGIN
    --RAISERROR('No rows exist, quit job', 16, 1);
    commit transaction usp_get_inactive_reports_email;
    --print 'commit'
    Return;
    END


commit transaction usp_get_inactive_reports_email;
    end try
    begin catch
        declare @error int, @message varchar(4000), @xstate int;
        select @error = ERROR_NUMBER(), @message = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @xstate = XACT_STATE();
        if @xstate = -1
            rollback;
        if @xstate = 1 and @trancount = 0
            rollback
        if @xstate = 1 and @trancount > 0
            rollback ;

        raiserror ('usp_get_inactive_reports_email: %d: %s', 16, 1, @error, @message) ;
        return;
    end catch   
end
```

[image: Some diagnostics showing locks when running SP]

Comment: A pet peeve, but it's not `;WITH` it's just `WITH`. The semicolon (`;`) goes at the end of *all* your statements, not just the start of those that need the **previous** statement properly terminated.

Comment: Sorry, I will take this on the future. Wonder if the save transaction is the problem.

Comment: Those global temp tables are killing you here. As pointed out below. But more to the point is that with global temp tables you have a whole list of other problems. Concurrency being a major problem. There are many things here that need to be rethought in order for this to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Global temporary tables are visible from multiple sessions, but they have locking just like regular tables.  So sessions can't read each other's uncommitted changes.  This includes uncommitted DDL, like CREATE TABLE or SELECT ... INTO.

What you have is a un-detectable deadlock between your sessions, equivalent to:

```
begin transaction
create table ##t(id int)
exec xp_cmdshell 'bcp "select * from ##t" queryout "c:\temp\foo.csv" -S "localhost" -T'
```

Your BCP session can't read from the table, and is waiting for its creation to be committed, and the stored procedure is waiting on BCP.